# Cursor keys leave insert mode in irb in vi mode

Tags: ruby, readline, irb

I am using vi-mode in irb by having a ~/.inputrc stating:

```
set editing-mode vi
```

Since I changed to ruby 1.9.3 and 2.0.0, IRB and the rails console started behaving differently.

Before I could use the left and right cursor arrow keys in insert mode and the cursor would move accordingly, staying in insert mode (like standard in vim).

Typing arrow left now deletes all characters till the end of the line and takes me right out of insert mode.
I am lost, why is this happening?

UPDATE:
How can I get irb to interpret the arrow keys as such and not as escape sequences?

Comment: Did you install with readlines support?

Comment: @vgoff: How can I find out?

Comment: @vgoff: "Readline" is defined, of class "Module" and has quite a lot of methods.

Comment: If you have set vi mode why are you using the arrow keys at all?  Use word movement instead, or h or l to move a single character.  That said, I set the `~/.inputrc` as you have and have no problems with the arrow keys.  This leads me to believe that you may not have the readlines package installed correctly.

Comment: Cross posted here: http://superuser.com/q/678711/169719

Comment: @vgoff: Is that bad? I figured it might be a more suited place to ask this specific question.

Comment: Not "bad" but to be avoided.  Sometimes they get moved from one place to another though.  That is beyond my pay grade.

Answer (score 0):

This is because Readline is interpreting the escape characters for the cursor keys. Left cursor is `ESC[D` which leaves insert mode and then deletes the rest of the line. Similarly cursor right will leave insert mode and `C`hange the rest of the line, up will `A`ppend to the rest of the line and down will go `B`ack a word.

I believe this could be the same thing as [bug #7859](http://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/7859#change-36333).